# HTML шаблон, сделать функциональным

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем привет!

Приобретён HTML шаблон. Вопрос заключается в том, как данный шаблон сделать рабочим, а именно, сделать функциональным. Нужно ли, все страницы переименовывать в html.php или .php или достаточно создать папку с functions.php и создать для каждого действия и страницы отдельный сценарий?

Проблема в том, что немного растерялся с чего начать, и очень хотелось бы услышать от Вас, именно от людей понимающих PHP MSQL, данный процесс, как всё это реализовывается.

Я не прошу, чтоб Вы мне всё подробно описывали как для чайника в PHP, просто реальные рекомендации, например, как бы вы реализовали.

Огромная просьба, пользователей, которые не понимают процесс но просто хотят покритиковать за подобный вопрос, не обращать внимание на данную тему. Только без обид и пожалуйста с пониманием. Так как очень хочу реализовать.

Изображения и ссылка на шаблон:

1. https://themeforest.net/item/classified-place-classified-multipurpose-template/19165145 - шаблон, который был здесь куплен.
2. а). http://prntscr.com/lv4sog - файлы в шаблоне, для более детального понимания
   б). http://prntscr.com/lv4td8 - файлы в шаблоне

Буду благодарен за дельные советы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще. 
Как правило верх(header) и низ(footer) на всех шаблонах идентичен. 
Поэтому верх и низ страницы помещаете в index.php, а серединку выносите в отдельный шаблон.
Необходимый шаблон подключаете на соответствующем URL. Например на главной http://site.com подключаете home.php, а на внутренней  http://site.com/contact  contact.php

Comment: Хмм, не плохо, теперь надо будет это всё дело себе представить и попробовать сделать. Спасибо за дельный совет. Я уж подумал, что нужно огромный functions.php создавать и создавать огромные сценарии.

Comment: Ну регистрацию и всевозможные проверки это для меня не проблема, хотя есть ступор, как сделать страницу после входа или регистрации пользователя, чтоб ссылка "Вход", исчезал, а появился только "Выход"

Comment: Для регистрации надо реализовать сценарий логинизации и если пользователь авторизовался, скрывать блок HTML кода например и выводить другой или сделать перенаправление на другую страницу.

Comment: Мг, понял Вас! Сейчас, буду думать...